# some files are suddenly disapear from eclipse folder

Tags: eclipse, installation

I downloaded eclipse and then extracted it and copy it to another drive I use it for the first time. It has all file and folder. 
after that I delete it and try to copy it again. but this time some files doesn't exist.
here is the picture of files:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try to redownload it from https://eclipse.org/downloads/ and reunpack it.